# Where are the Logs for Jobs Submitted Through Flink Dashboard?

Tags: apache-flink

I recently put up Flink on two servers in Google Cloud to test some things out with them.  I created a standalone cluster, with one of them being the Job Manager, and both of them having a Task Manager.  In order to test the cluster, I submitted a custom job through the Dashboard interface (using an SSH proxy).  The job runs fairly well (albeit with some independent and unrelated issues).

The issue is that I can't find the logs for the job that was submitted from the Dashboard.  I've checked in `/tmp`, in `$FLINK_HOME`, and the root `$HOME`, but I can't seem to find them anywhere.  The documentation doesn't seem to note where the log files are stored.  So, my question is, where are the log files for these jobs?

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: Nope!  I ended up not using Flink at all, because there were too many issues.  I just used Akka (which sounds weird, considering it's not even meant for the same kind of applications, but it works, and it works _really well._)

Answer (score -1):

You could set the log file in following location:

in ubuntu:

```
export FLINK_CONF_DIR=/YOUR/CONF folder location
```

Comment: This isn't really clear.  Where should the command be executed?  What should the value actually be?  How does this correlate to submitting a job through the dashboard?  What does `FLINK_CONF_DIR` do, and what does the documentation say it does?